# Why isn't this working

Tags: java

this code is supposed to have you pick a # then by telling the pc is its to low or too high you lower the range of the pc's guess but the range does not seem to change could someone help  `enter code here.:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 100;
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("whats the number");
int ans = i.nextInt();
int guess = (int)(Math.random()* 100 + 1);
while(ans != guess)
{
    System.out.println(guess);
    System.out.println("is that number to high)1 or to low)2");
    int p = i.nextInt();
    if(p == 1)
    {
        if(guess < max)
        {
            max = guess;
            guess = (int)(Math.random()*max + min); 
        }
        else
        {
            guess = (int)(Math.random()*max + min);
        }
    }
    if(p == 2)
    {
        if(guess > min)
        {
            min = guess;
            guess = (int)(Math.random()*max + min); 
        }
        else
        {
            guess = (int)(Math.random()*max + min);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(guess + " is right");
```

Comment: define what is not working

Comment: well when i run the program say i pick 50 as my number then the PC guesses 75 then i say that is to high it should set 75 as the max and should never guess anything higher then that but the problem is....it does guess higher then that

Comment: try debugging `line by line`

Comment: I get *line cannot be resolved to a type* and *Syntax error on token "line", ; expected*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your `guess` variable calculation method.

You want to guess number which is between min and max. So you can use [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range).

```
guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Below you can find full code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumbersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int min = 1;
        int max = 101;
        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("whats the number");
        int ans = i.nextInt();
        Random rand = new Random(); //NOTE
        int guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //NOTE
        while (ans != guess) {
            System.out.println(guess);
            System.out.println("is that number to high)1 or to low)2");
            int p = i.nextInt();
            if (p == 1) {
                if (guess < max) {
                    max = guess;
                    guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //NOTE
                } else {
                    guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //NOTE
                }
            }
            if (p == 2) {
                if (guess > min) {
                    min = guess;
                    guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //NOTE
                } else {
                    guess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //NOTE
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(guess + " is right");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of a noob at this

Comment: @B.Stewart If this answer help you, don't forget to accept :)